# MatPlotLib: Control Ind Increments

Tags: python, matplotlib

Given this chart:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcdefaults()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Example data
people = ('Tom', 'Dick', 'Harry', 'Slim')
y_pos = np.arange(len(people))
performance = 3 + 10 * np.random.rand(len(people))

plt.barh(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.4)

plt.show()
```

[image]
You'll notice that the y-axis ind (index?) is in increments of 0.5.
However, if I add a person to the list of people and re-run the code, the index is in increments of 1.

**Is there any way to control the increments so that they are always in units of 1?**

*Update*

If I can somehow get the increment (0.5 or 1) from the y-axis, that would be just as good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `yticks` function like this:

```
plt.yticks(range(len(y_pos)))
```

Comment: I need to delete that. It's for another purpose that I'm asking. I need the ind values to always display in the same units regardless of how many bars there are.

Comment: @DanceParty2 The bars depends on the number of people aren't they? So that does exactly what you wish

Comment: Not always. I have another bar chart that starts increment of 1 for 6 bars or more, whereas this one starts at 5 bars or more.

Comment: @DanceParty2 I can't understand what is the problem. Whenever you use `barh` you sent  a list of values as a parameter and you can send the `range` of the length of that list to `yticks`

Comment: Not sure what you mean (I probably have seen it, but can't recall based on your comment). Will that allow me to specify the increments shown on the axis as in 0.5 or 1?

Comment: @DanceParty2 did you try it? If you have another question please give  a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)